# Passing arguments through bash script to C program

Tags: c, bash, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a program that accept file names as arguments in a bash script, then passes them to a C program that replaces spaces with underscores, then the bash script uses that to rename the file.

For example, the input would be

```
Bash bash_script "test test test.txt"
```

and the file would be renamed `test_test_test.txt`.

My problem is that when I run this, it tells me that I'm using `mv` incorrectly. Why is this? I'm new to bash, so I'm sorry for using program/script incorrectly.

My C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char * file = argv[1];

    while(i<=256){  //max file size is 256 characters on mac
        if (argc != 2)
            printf("Please provide one file name.");
        else if(file[i] == ' ')
            file[i] = '_';
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s \n", file);
    return 0;
}
```

My Bash program:

```
#! /bin/bash

VAR = "C_program '$@'"
mv $1 $VAR
```

Comment: One answer is to actually use `tr` in your shell script (ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr )

Comment: What about tabs and newlines in the file name? What about other control characters? What happens if the name passed to the script doesn't contain spaces?  What happens if the argument is "`abc def`" but there is already a file "`abc_def`"?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> ```
> VAR = "C_program '$@'"
> ```

doesn't do what you want. And your `mv` line is broken too.

```
VAR=$(C_program "$@")
mv "$1" "$VAR"
```

Also, your C program doesn't exit with an error when an error is detected.

Also, `sed` and `tr` are existing programs that are suitable alternatives to writing your C program to transliterate (*translate*) characters in strings.

Also, `rename`/`prename` are existing (Perl) programs that handle rename files with regular expression pattern functionality to rename files, which may be already available on your system(s).

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, I would not shell out to a custom C program to do this.

Here's an equivalent shell script (not requiring `tr`, `sed` or any programs besides `bash` and `mv`):

```
mv "$1" "${1// /_}"
```

In your specific problem, you are not setting your `VAR` properly. Shell scripts cannot accept spaces around the `=` when setting variables, and you need to use backticks or `$()` to execute an external program. So, properly written, you want

```
VAR="$(C_program "$@")"
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems with the mv $1 "C_program '$@'"

- $1 needs double quotes -> "$1"
- "C_program '$@'" should be `C_program '$1'` or $(C_program '$@')

however this can be done more efficiently with

```
IFS="
"
for x in $@; do
    mv "$x" "${x// /_}"
done
```

Comment: Use `for x in "$@"` because the input names generally have spaces in them, which will cause troubles if you don't double quote `"$@"`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I initially had `while ([ "$1" ]) do mv "$1" "${1// /_}";shift;done` but (over-)simplified it to this.  Fixed with IFS, hopefully none of the files have return characters (though it is possible since its not a '/')

Comment: Better not to mess with `IFS` and simply use the notation that works regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the results than I would suggest simply replace the bash script and custom C program with a single short Bourne or POSIX shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
NEW_FILE_NAME= `echo $1 | tr ' ' _  `
mv $1 $NEW_FILE_NAME
```

Otherwise

You want the shell script to run your C program (I'll refer to it as `todash` for simplicity) before setting the shell variable `VAR`. This is done using the *backtick* ` (located near upper right corner of US keyboards with tilde, '~') operation.

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR= `todash $1`
mv $1 $VAR
```

For todash.c I'll suggest a couple of mostly small improvements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char * filename;  
   /* Program operates on filename, not file or its contents, so use a variable
      name that reflect that. Good variable names make debugging easier.
    */

   if (argc != 2) {
     printf("Please provide one file name.");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;  /* or exit(EXIT_FAILURE); */
   } else {
     /* Only set filename, once known that argv[1] is not NULL (empty) */
     filename = argv[1];
   }

   /* Use a simple for loop
    * PATH_MAX is a standard system constant included with limits.h
    */
   for (i = 0; (i < PATH_MAX) && (filename[i] != '\0'); i++) {
      if (filename[i] == ' ') {
         filename[i] = '_';
      }
   }
   printf("%s \n", filename);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The added length is only my additional inline comments.

The largest change was untangling the `argc` `if` comparison from the `while` loop, which once simplified, become a classic example of where to use a `for` loop.

And for your sanity, and those around you, use braces (curly brackets) around conditional blocks of code. Just because you are allowed to not include them, does not mean you should (not include them). Programs tend to live beyond their original intention and expand in the future. Avoid making mistakes later by including them now.